# SQL Server Agent will not start - times out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-agent

On my localhost, I am running 2014 (not express).  I need to create a job, and for that, I need the Agent service to run.  But I can't get it started.

I have been googling the snot out of this, but so far no luck.

In the Windows Logs, under System, I have only this:

> The SQL Server Agent (SQL2014) service failed to start due to the following error:
> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

and

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the SQL Server Agent (SQL2014) service to connect.

and

> The server {1B1F472E-3221-4826-97DB-2C2324D389AE} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.

Not very helpful.  I found the SQLAGENT.OUT file, but there is nothing recent in it.  The last entry is from over a month ago. None the less, this is the contents of the file:

```
2017-10-26 15:35:51 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 12.0.5207.0 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 4980
2017-10-26 15:35:51 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is NT Service\SQLAgent$SQL2014.
2017-10-26 15:35:56 - ? [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...
2017-10-26 15:35:57 - ? [000] 
2017-10-26 15:35:57 - ? [101] SQL Server EBDEVELOPER\SQL2014 version 12.00.5207 (0 connection limit)
2017-10-26 15:35:57 - ? [102] SQL Server ODBC driver version 11.00.2100
2017-10-26 15:35:57 - ? [103] NetLib being used by driver is DBNETLIB; Local host server is EBDEVELOPER\SQL2014
2017-10-26 15:35:57 - ? [310] 8 processor(s) and 16315 MB RAM detected
2017-10-26 15:35:57 - ? [339] Local computer is EBDEVELOPER running Windows NT 6.2 (9200) 
2017-10-26 15:35:57 - ? [432] There are 13 subsystems in the subsystems cache
2017-10-26 15:35:58 - ? [129] SQLAgent$SQL2014 starting under Windows NT service control
2017-10-26 15:35:58 - + [475] Database Mail is not enabled for agent notifications.
2017-10-26 15:35:58 - + [396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect
2017-10-26 15:37:00 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'xxxxx', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
2017-10-26 15:38:00 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'xxxxx', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
2017-10-26 15:39:00 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'xxxxx', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
2017-10-26 15:40:00 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'xxxxx', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
2017-10-26 15:41:00 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'xxxxx', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
2017-10-26 15:41:33 - ? [131] SQLAgent$SQL2014 service stopping due to a stop request from a user, process, or the OS...
2017-10-26 15:41:35 - ? [000] Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 15457)
2017-10-26 15:41:35 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

(The `xxxxx` was the name of the former developer who used to use this laptop.  I am his replacement. For his sake, I removed his name.)

Following some advice I found on other threads, I ran this against the master database:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options','1'
RECONFIGURE
go

sp_configure 'Agent XPs','1'
RECONFIGURE
go
```

It returned this:

> Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

Service still would not start (although it looks like nothing changed, so I wasn't surprised).

I've tried to start it from within the normal Windows Services, and from within SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In the Properties, I have tried to logon as all of the options on the Built-in account dropdown. I've also tried the admin account I use to connect to the DB from within SSMS.

The service is set to StartType automatic.

I'm not sure what else to try.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you have a DCOM error I would suggest trying something with the DCOM settings. Perhaps [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/i-get-event-id10010-error-server-did-not-register/dcdacaa3-d894-4d4b-ada5-56817b072905?auth=1) may help. I assume the SQL Server service is starting, have you tried with the same user? Or have you tried changing the *SQL Server service* account user? If it's the old dev, maybe their account permissions are off and you need to use a new one.

Comment: The settings described in that article are already set as suggested. However, I appreciate the help, and I will spend more time researching that particular error, which I hadn't done yet.